# Using html2pdf to print data from form post in PHP as a PDF file

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, html2pdf

I am trying to get some data from a form post and outputting it in a PDF file with html2pdf on the same page. However, when trying to post the form data to the same page it won't open the PDF file, probably because the rest of the PHP file will come after the if($_POST). If I remove the code in the "else" part it downloads fine.

Is there any way around this? Or a better way to do it? I am creating form data with javascript so I need to post it to php somehow, but the code below is just a simplified example. Doesn't matter to me if solution is jquery/javascript/php but I essentially need to post an array to this PDF output after user action.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sweets'])){

// get the HTML
ob_start();
?>
<page backtop="35mm" backbottom="20mm" backleft="15mm" backright="15mm">
    <div id="p1-content">
        <h3>Mer test</h3>
        <p>Normalement une valeur devrait vous être demandée, puis affichée</p>
    </div>
</page>

<?php
// PDF script to execute
$content = ob_get_clean();
// convert to PDF
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/html2pdf/vendor/autoload.php');

try
{
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en');    
    $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
    $html2pdf->Output('testprint.pdf','D');
}

catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
    echo $e;
    exit;
}
?>
<?php
} else {
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sendData").click(function () {
        var str = "";
        $("select[name='sweets'] option:selected").each(function () {
            str += $(this).text() + " ";
        });
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data:  $("form#a").serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                jQuery(".res").html(data);
                $('#test').html(data);
            }
        });
        var str = $("form").serialize();
        $(".res").text(str);
    });
});
</script>
<div id="test"></div>
<form id="a" action="" method="post">
    <select name="sweets" >
        <option>Chocolate</option>
        <option selected="selected">Candy</option>
        <option>Taffy</option>
        <option>Caramel</option>
        <option>Fudge</option>
        <option>Cookie</option>
    </select>
</form>
<button class="sendData">Send Data</button>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use [example09 on the HTML2PDF page](http://html2pdf.fr/en/example) to post to the page itself, I only wish the examples were presented a bit better so I could have seen this right away.